# VirtualBox networking between VM's

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have 2 virtual machines that are currently configured as Bridge Network connected to the NIC... so that, my router gives them the IP address.

The problem with this, is that from the VM's I can ping the router and the host and it works, however, if from host I try to ping any VM's they don't respond. Even when trying to ping from a VM to the other VM, ping does not repond.

When I change network setting to be Internal Network, the APIPA is assigned, so it is not my solution.

Is there a way to have all VM's and host connect each other?

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: They should all be able to reach each other with your current setup. If the guests aren't responding to pings something else must be going on like maybe they have firewalls blocking the pings. What OS are running on the guests?

Comment: Windows 7 Enterprise

Comment: The Windows firewall blocks pings by default.

Comment: That.. that was the problem... but related the same... how can I access the guest using its name instead of its ip?

Comment: The simplest way to do that is to add the other PC's name/ip address to the `hosts` file on each PC.

Comment: Yes.. it's simplest, but I wanted to avoid adding the names to the host file in each PC... i thought there was a way to broadcast the name to the network automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to have all VM's and host connect each other?

According to your description, the way your network is set up should be able to ping each other. If you can't ping each other, it's possible that the firewall blocked the ping. Try to check the firewall.

How can I access the guest using its name instead of its ip?

To add the other PC's name ip address to the hosts file on each PC. Or create a new DNS server and point other VMs to this DNS server.